# Swift dictionary on iOS 7

Tags: ios7, dictionary, swift

I need to initialize a Dictionary on Swift for an app that works on iOS 7+.
On iOS 8 everything works fine, but on iOS 7 the dictionary is always empty.

I tried

```
 var parameters = Dictionary<String, String>()
 parameters["grant_type"] = "password"
```

and also

```
 let parameters = ["grant_type" : "password"]
```

On both cases the result is

`Printing description of parameters:
([String : String!]) parameters = {}`

It's a Swift bug or I did something wrong here? 
FYI: I'm using Xcode 6.1 (Swift 1.1)

Comment: At what point do you initialise and print this dictionary?

Comment: @Kirsteins: The init is at the beginning of a func, the print is done right after the code is executed. Also, an extra detail: I use this dictionary for a web-service login and the problem is not on printing on console, because on server-side from iOS 7 I don't receive the data. Tested already with two different Xcode projects.

Comment: I don't know if it's a bug or not, but worst comes to worst you can fall back on NSDictionary. Also, try making it optional and just initiating it with `var parameter: Dictionary<String, String>?`

Comment: Can you paste the entire function?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, swift dictionaries seem to work, but debugging will show empty values.  The answer is, to debug, cast from Swift dictionary to NSDictionary

```
print(swiftDictionary as NSDictionary)
```

Original

Swift Dictionaries do not work in iOS 7 for whatever reason.  he workaround is to use NSDictionary.